# active Attribute Casting making project environment fail - Laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5.1

We have implemented the Attribute Casting in Laravel project for active field

```
protected $casts = [
    'active' => 'boolean',
];
```

and the field is in TINYINT (they are just synonyms) but the fact, since the time we have implemented that code in our Model it didn't thew any error and worked seamlessly but when we deployed on Production environment it threw 404 error so we changed the environment to local `APP_ENV=local` to check why its throwing error but when the environment switched to local it worked mysteriously so again we switched back to `APP_ENV=production` and thew 404 error so

> Attribute Casting

is affecting the environment of the Application and can't find out why?

Comment: How are you sure that this cast is the cause of this problem? What does this `active` property do exactly?

Comment: @Jerodev I have tried to change the app environment and test it in everyone's machines and the same result. and `active` field is to check if the Project is active or not